# Web API handle uploaded files for delete

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

ok I have this code that handle a file been upload through a simple web form

```
CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\Images");
//var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\Images");
var Image = "";
var Dir = "";
var CurrentPath = "";
string UploadType = "";
string ImageName = "";
// Read the form data.
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

// Show all the key-value pairs.
foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
{
    foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
   {
      if (key == "uploadType") UploadType = val;
      if (key == "imageName") ImageName = val;
      //Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
   }
}

foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
{
   //Debug.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
   //Debug.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
   Image = Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName);
   Dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file.LocalFileName);
   CurrentPath = file.LocalFileName;
}

if (UploadType == "update")
{
   File.Delete(Dir + "\\" + Image);
   File.Move(CurrentPath, Dir + "\\" + Image);
   Imagen = ImageName;
}

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Image);
```

as some docs mention using await will cause the read process to be async, my problem is that I need to know when the file has been saved into the folder cause I want to delete it after if the `UploadType` form field is `==` to update, but it seems like when try this line

```
File.Delete(Dir + "\\" + Image);
```

the image is has not been saved yet and I got an error that the image don't exist, so my question is, how I can tell or be sure the image is ready in the dir? how can I tell the async process ends, thanks for any help on this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.Exists` is the method you should use.

*Aside* You should be using `Path.Combine` instead of building the path with concatenation.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so that means the problem isn't with the async process? when I try File.Exists that image is already saved?

Comment: @goseta you should put a lock for that file somewhere.

Comment: I really thank you for all your replies, I very new in .NET, my background is in other languages, can u be kind to point me out to some docs maybe, I understand the lock reason, but no idea of the syntax thanks!